MAUI Blazor Hybrid and static resources
I am developping a MAUI application and during the process I decided to use Blazor component so I switched my project to a MAUI Blazor Hybrid application and use Blazor components through BlazorWebView.
I don't how I should use the XAML mechanism to retrieve colors on the Blazor side, though.
For example I have in Resources/Styles/Color.xaml
<Color x:Key="Primary">#CABEFF</Color>

And in Blazor code, I use css to style my elements like this:
<style>
    #container {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

How should I proceed to retrieve "Primary" in my css ?

You can also use the color code:#CABEFF in the css. There is no way to do that directly. You need to get the "Primary" in the code behind and then set it in the js.
